# Does promise.get_future() have to be called before setting a value?

Tags: c++, promise, future

From http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/future/promise/get_future/:

> After this function has been called, the promise is expected to make its shared state ready at some point [...]

I'm unsure if this implies that this order of operations is mandatory:

1. get_future()
2. set_value()

Would it also be possible to get the future from the promise only after a value has been set?

Comment: Can you show an example where it would make sense to call `set_value` before `get_future`?

Comment: @mike Let's say I create a promise, pass it to some other thread (e.g. by capturing it by reference in a lambda which is then executed on some thread), and then basically do promise.get_future().get().

Comment: @FelixDombek Are you sure that doesn't have a data race?

Comment: @Caleth I don't think it matters. If set_value can be called *after* the call to get_future, then get() will just either wait or return immediately. So no matter whether the thread executes first or second, this line should be safe.

Comment: As we can see in [C++ standard issues](https://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/issue2412), calling `get_future` & `set_value` may produce a data race.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I see there is no such limitation. The only two cases when `std::promise::set_value` leads to error are:

1. Promise object has no shared state (this can occur when promise object is being moved):

   ```
   promise<int> p;
   auto p2 = std::move(p);
   p.set_value(42); // error
   ```
2. The shared state already stores a value or exception:

   ```
   promise<int> p;
   p.set_value(0);
   p.set_value(42); // error
   ```

   or

   ```
   promise<int> p;
   try 
   {
       throw std::runtime_error("Some error");
   } 
   catch(...) 
   {
       p.set_exception(std::current_exception());
       p.set_value(42); // error
   }
   ```

But there is no limitation for `get_future` to be called before.